# Get Custom String for Key based off Values Variable Name in Class?

Tags: php, oop, naming-conventions

Trying to convert a procedural script to OOP.

In my procedural script I define `$metadata = array()` before I define variables in a `foreach` loop like such:

```
foreach ($productdata as $productinfo) {

    $price = (float) $productinfo['Price'];
    $regularprice = (float) $productinfo['RegularPrice'];
```

And then proceeded to manually input/type what I wanted the `key` value (`_cost` and `_regular_cost`)

```
    $metadata[] =
        [
            'key' => '_cost',
            'value' => $price
        ];

    $metadata[] =
        [
            'key' => '_regular_cost',
            'value' => $regularprice
        ];
```

Now I am trying to compact it into a class, but am uncertain how to generate these `key` => `_{value}` names.

Something I've thought to try.. could be totally off.

So the name of my class is `WooCommerceController`

```
Class WooCommerceController
{
    protected $metadata;

    static $metadata_keys = ['_cost', '_regular_cost'];
```

Then I thought about making the class function either accept an individual metadata value

```
public function generateMetaData(string $metadatavalue) {
```

or an array of values

```
public function generateMetaData(array $metadatavalue_array) {
```

but no matter which I can think of, even if I have access to the `$metadata_keys` static variable, I can't think of a way for the function to distinguish between for example `$price` and `$regularprice`.

The only thing I can think of is to pass it in a strict indexed way (ensure the same order of values being passed congruent with the values in `WooCommerceController::$metadata_keys`)..

or I thought maybe I could name my variables --- instead of `$price`, rename them `$_cost` --- and then I was just researching methods to `converting variables name to string` but this seems like it is more of a hackish solution

Can anyone think of a more proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how proper this is still very much learning OOP and OOP design patterns but I came up with this solution:

```
Class WooCommerceController
{
    protected $metadata = array();
    public function generateMetaData(string $metadatakeyname, string $metadatavalue) {
            $this->metadata[] =
                [
                    'key' => $metadatakeyname,
                    'value' => $metadatavalue
                ];
            return $this->metadata;
    }
```

And in context using it like this:

```
       $metadata = $woo->generateMetaData('_cost', $price);
       $metadata = $woo->generateMetaData('_regular_cost', $price);
```

And it appears to fill up the array in the class context (`this->metadata`) and also each additional statement adds to the `$metadata` array out of the class context.